# Is the arrival time of a point in a Poisson process distributed uniformly at random?

Tags: uniform-distribution, poisson-process

We are given a homogeneous Poisson point process with parameter $m$ on the non-negative half-line. Suppose we know there are exactly $k$ points in the interval $[0,T]$. Pick a point $a$ uniformly at random from these $k$ points.

I want to show that the arrival time $T_a$ of $a$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,T]$.

In [some course notes](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MAS338/PP%20and%20uniform%20d-n.pdf) I found a link between Poisson processes and the uniform distribution, but I can't make it work as I have little experience in probability theory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: This is not homework - I'm trying to understand Proposition 20 in [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2394319).

Comment: Hint: If you rearrange the time line, mapping time $\tau$ to zero and taking the segment $[0,\tau]$ tino $[T-\tau,T]$ then the points produced by the poisson process on $[0,T]$, mapped to the new points, are still poisson distributed, and with the same rate.  Prove that (easy since the prob of a point in a tiny interval is the same regardless of the interval position). From there, argue that the likelihood of any point among a **fixed** set of $k$ poisson-distributed points is invariant under transformations by $\tau$ (mod $T$).

Comment: Thanks, @MarkFischler! I managed to prove the first part but can you elaborate on your last sentence a little more?